# How to know the updated version number of android library to use in gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am having a problem while using android libraries to android studio.
How to know the latest version of the library which is appended in the end of the statement in the gradle file.

For example : If I want to add the Google play services, I can add this line

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

If I updated the library using sdk manager,then how to get the new version number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually after updating my android sdk check at

> Project Structure > app > Dependencies > + button > Library dependency

[image]

Comment: I am using 1.3.2 studio. I am not getting any window after clicking the library dependency option

Comment: I am also on 1.3.2 and it work.. you mean you dont get the list of library dependencies?

Comment: Strange! Do you have Android SDK Build-tools installed ?

Comment: yes , all build tools are installed. But windows are showing up for module and file dependency options

Comment: another quick check.. are Android support repository and Android support Library installed ?